# What is the measure of the angle CGF in the given figure?

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line

[image]

What I could gather:
$$CX=CY=CE=CF=r$$
$$\measuredangle CEB=\measuredangle CFD=90^{\circ}.$$
$$\measuredangle XCE=65^{\circ}$$
$$\measuredangle CEF= \measuredangle CFE$$

[image]

Please help me solve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\measuredangle ECF=90^{\circ}$, $CE=CF$ and $\Delta BCE\cong\Delta DCF$, we obtain:
$$\measuredangle CGF=45^{\circ}+25^{\circ}=70^{\circ}.$$

Comment: Sir, why is angle ECF =90 degrees?

Comment: @Soumee Take $\Delta BCE$ and rotate around $C$ on $90^{\circ}$. We obtain: $B\rightarrow D$ and tangent line $BE\rightarrow DF$. Thus, $E\rightarrow F$, which says that $\measuredangle ECF=90^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Note that $\measuredangle GCF$ is also $65^\circ$, and $\angle ECF$ is right. But $\triangle ECF$ is isosceles, so what is $\measuredangle CFG$?

Comment: Sir, why is angle ECF =90 degrees?

Comment: @Soumee One way to see this: $\measuredangle ECD = 25^\circ$

Comment: @Soumee Another way to see this is that triangle $CFD$ is a rotation by $90^\circ$ of triangle $CEB$.